# Spherical Refracting Surfaces

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics

Why when given a question to find the image of a point object in a spherical refracting surface do you have to consider that there are two surfaces refracting the light?

I assumed that one could simply use the equation,

$\frac{n_a}{s}$ + $\frac{n_b}{s'}$ = $\frac{n_b - n_a}{R}$

and solve for $s'$ to get the image distance, but why do I also have to calculate

$\frac{n_b}{-(s'-d)}$ + $\frac{n_a}{s_2'}$ = $\frac{n_a - n_b}{-R}$

and then when I have solved for $s_2'$ add R and **that** is the image distance.

**Example**

> A candle is placed $60 cm$ from a glass sphere with a $5cm$ radius. The index of refraction of the glass sphere is $n_b = 1.5$. How far from the center of the glass sphere will the image of the candle be?

**My answer**

$s= 60 -5 = 55 cm$

$R = 5 cm$

$n_a= 1$ and $n_b=1.5$

$\frac{1}{55}$ + $\frac{1.5}{s'}$ = $\frac{1.5 - 1}{5}$   $=>$ $s' =+18.33 cm$

Answer: The image will be $18.33 cm$ from the center

**Answer provided as correct**

$\frac{1}{55}$ + $\frac{1.5}{s'}$ = $\frac{1.5 - 1}{5}$ => $s' =18.33 cm$

$\frac{1.5}{-(18.33-10)}$ + $\frac{1}{s_2'}$ = $\frac{1 - 1.5}{-5}$ $=>$ $s'_2 = 3.6 cm$

$s'_3 = 3.6 +5 = 8.6 cm$

Answer: The image will be $8.6 cm$ from the center of the glass sphere

Comment: Notice that both answers, yours and the correct one, place the image outside of the sphere.

Comment: Does "Answer key" mean "Provided answer" or "Correct answer"?

Comment: It is the answer our teacher said is correct @VolkerSiegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider two surfaces because the light is refracted on two surfaces:

- The surface of the sphere where the light of the candle shines on.
- The surface of the same sphere where the light exits the sphere.

In between these surfaces, the light travels in a direction not parallel to the direction before the first refraction, or after the second.

Note that the sphere could be "spherical" only on the first surface, and different on the second. For example a half sphere, where the second surface is flat.